# Concat Flux with its count (or another reduce function)

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is it possible to proceed(concat) a Flux with some reduce function on it, for example number of passed elements?

That is, for example, to turn a

```
Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("a", "b", "c")) //note source flux could be read only once
```

to Flux that will evaluate in

```
"a", "b", "c", "3"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Flux<String> source = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("a", "b", "c"));

  Flux<String> fork = source.publish().autoConnect(2);
  ConnectableFlux<Long> counter = fork.count().flux().replay(1);
  counter.connect();

  Flux<String> result = fork.concatWith(counter.map(Object::toString));

  result.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Notes:

1. `.publish()` is used to broadcast the same sequence to multiple subscribers. `autoConnect(2)` prevents an early subscription and consumption of the sequence. Exactly 2 subscribers are expected.
2. It is known that `Flux.concat()` subscribes lazily: the second subscription is created once the first sequence completes, but in your case you need two active subscribers for the same source sequence at the same time. This is solved by creating a `ConnectableFlux` and explicitly calling its `connect()` method. (There is no `ConnectableMono` class, thus the counter is converted from `Mono` to a `Flux`). The value is obtained early and is cached, and will be replayed once `Flux.concat()` subscribes to it.

Regarding the issue with `Flux.concat()` and its laziness: I just noticed that `Flux.mergeSequential()` is documented as an alternative to `concat` that subscribes eagerly.

Thus my code can be simplified by using `mergeSequential()` instead of `concat()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Flux<String> source = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("a", "b", "c"));

  Flux<String> fork = source.publish().autoConnect(2);
  Mono<Long> counter = fork.count();

  Flux<String> result = Flux.mergeSequential(fork, counter.map(Object::toString));

  result.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Just thought both could be accepted at once. Also learned new stuff from this answer.

Comment: I updated the answer with a better solution: using `mergeSequential` instead of `concat`. It allows to simplify the code, omitting `ConnectableFlux` and caching (`replay`).

Answer (score 1):

Since your flux can be read only once, I had to make this workaround:

I define my mapper like this:

```
public class MyMapper implements Function<String, String> {

  private AtomicInteger atomicInteger;

  public MyMapper(AtomicInteger atomicInteger) {
    this.atomicInteger = atomicInteger;
  }

  @Override
  public String apply(String s) {
    atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
    return s;
  }

}
```

and finally the main code will look like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    MyMapper mapper = new MyMapper(count);
    Flux<String> f = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("a", "b", "c"));
    Flux<String> output = f.map(mapper).concatWith(Mono.fromCallable(() -> Integer.toString(count.get())));
    output.doOnNext(System.out::println).blockLast();

  }
```

This prints out:

```
a
b
c
3
```

---

Your problem doesn't require a "reducing" function.
You can simply achieve this using:

```
  public Flux<String> concat(Flux<String> sourceFlux){
    Mono<String> m = sourceFlux.collectList().map(List::size).map(count -> Integer.toString(count));
    return sourceFlux.concatWith(m);
  }
```

Comment: 1. That will collect all values in memory, so at least it looks like it's better to use custom .collect, for example .collect(AtomicInteger::new, (countCollector, value) -> countCollector.incrementAndGet()).map(AtomicInteger::get)

Comment: 2. That will read Flux twice, what even could be not possible. I updated an example at question

Comment: What is that method, you mentioned above in your 1st comment? it's not even compiling. Is it something hypothetical method u are  suggesting?

Comment: Method Flux.collect(Supplier<E> containerSupplier, BiConsumer<E, ? super T> collector) is available in reactor-core-3.3.2 i'm using

Comment: Ok got your problem. Your flux is built from stream. And after reading once, it is closed. So you cant do `concatWith`

Comment: TBH I am too unable to find any solution for this at this moment.. Probably there is some other way, can you please mention what's the real problem?

Comment: @G.Domozhirov Finally I could find a working code.. please check. Hope it suffices your need

Comment: Looks like CustomType is redundant. Field CustomType.count not used. AtomicInteger is enogh. Also Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just...) could be simplified to Mono.fromCallable(()-> count.get). Looks like it works

Comment: @G.Domozhirov My Bad. Did that in a hurry. Updated the answer. Please accept if it helped you.